# Restore a database after re-appearance of default nodes, properties and relationships appear after restart in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

After deleting the existing graph directory in data/graph.db, I created the sets of relationships, nodes and relations. But after a restart of neo4j, the previously existing nodes, relationships etc. appeared again.

Can I restore my graph database? Why did those re-appear? How can I have a clear database?

Comment: 1: Make sure you are not running multiple instances of neo4j.
   2: Make sure neo4j is configured to correctly pick up the data folder location

Comment: 1: Only one instance running. 2: # location of the database directory 
org.neo4j.server.database.location=data/graph.db, where in data/ directory I am having graph.db/ graph.db.old/ and log/.

Comment: Ok. How do you know the older data is still there - via webadmin ? What OS you have?

Comment: I see the data in the web interface, i.e. via the webadmin. Ubuntu 12, 3.2.0-23-generic.